# Como eu crio um novo método a um constructor?

Tags: javascript

Existe um constructor Date (que é o constructor de datas que já vem no JS), e eu gostaria de criar um método lastYear() que trouxesse o "ano = ano-1" (para fins de exemplo e aprendizado).

Eu sei que eu poderia muito bem fazer isso usando o `prototype`:

```js
Date.prototype.lastYear = function(){
  return this.getFullYear() - 1;
}

console.log(new Date('1900-10-10').lastYear());
```

Porém, dessa forma eu aprendi nos livros que isso não é saudável para o compiler, já que você está alterando alterando a cadeia de protótipo natural do javascript.

Então eu gostaria de entender como eu poderia fazer isso da melhor forma usando classes:

```js
class Newfunc {
  constructor(){
    this.Date = Date
    this.lastYear();
  }

  lastYear(Date) {
    return this.Date.getFullYear() -1
  }

class Date extends Newfunc

new Date('1900-10-10').lastYear()
//expected result: '1899'
```

Sem sucesso, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Porém, dessa forma eu aprendi nos livros que isso não é saudável para
>   o compiler, já que você está alterando alterando a cadeia de protótipo
>   natural do javascript.

Onde você leu isso? Alterar o `prototype` de uma classe pode se tornar um problema sim, mas por causa de colisões, não porque você está "alterando a cadeia de protótipo natural", seja lá o que isso significa.

Alterar o `prototype` é uma ideia ruim especialmente em frameworks, imagine se bibliotecas como `jQuery` e `lodash` ambas implementassem um método `each` no `prototype` do `Array`, mas cada um desses métodos te dá os argumentos na função de callback em ordem diferente. Fórmula para desastre.

Isso não significa que não seja possível criar propriedades para o `prototype` de forma segura. Eu apenas sugeriria fazer isso utilizando o `Object.defineProperty` porque dessa forma as propriedades criadas serão não-`enumeraveis`

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'lastYear', {
    value() {
        return this.getFullYear() -1
    }
})
```

Todavia se você acha melhor estender a classe `Date`, você precisaria declarar um classe estendendo `Date`, não declarar uma classe e então tentar estender ela em `Date`, isso nem é possível, e se fosse, você cairia no mesmo problema anterior.

Exemplo:

```js
class CustomDate extends Date {
  lastYear() {
    return this.getFullYear() -1;
  }
}

var data = new CustomDate();
console.log(data.lastYear());
```

Comment: É, concordo com tudo o que você disse. Na verdade eu havia lido sobre não usar prototype, mas na verdade era isso mesmo que você tinha dito.